# how to handle multiple slugs in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

How would I get the work done to access a site like `example.com/<company_slug>/teams/<team_slug>`.

Of course my Team-Model points via foreignkey to company but it gets errors when I add this in my urls.py

```
path('<slug>/teams/<slug>', views.TeamDetail.as_view(), name="TeamDetail"),
```

but if I do this

```
path('<company_slug>/teams/<team_slug>', views.TeamDetail.as_view(), name="TeamDetail"),
```

then there is no error but I get a status 405 method not allowed. Even the  [example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#example_2) of drf doesn't really help (was using it to even try slug + pk not slug + slug)

### Edit

I refactored the code, because what I had was nonsense .. probably still is, now getting a new error message

> get_object() missing 1 required positional argument: 'team_slug'

So the idea here is:

> if user is not in the requested company's team or is anonymous= 404
>
> if user is not in that company = 404
>
> if user is in that company and in that team = 200

```
class TeamDetail(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
        serializer_class = TeamDetailSerializer
        lookup_field = 'slug'

    def get_object(self, company_slug, team_slug):
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            raise Http404()
        elif self.request.user.company:
            user = self.request.user
            company = Company.objects.get(company_slug=slug)
            team = Team.objects.get(team_slug=slug)
            if user.company != company:
                raise Http404()
            else:
                if user.team != team:
                    raise Http404
                else:
                    return team
        else:
            raise Http404()

    def get(self, request, company_slug, team_slug, format=None):
        team = self.get_object(team_slug)
        serializer = TeamDetailSerializer(team)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Add your TeamDetail view implementation to see how you handle it.

Comment: hi i have edited the question!

Answer (score 0):

so i have found a solution thanks this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48048066/django-rest-framework-multiple-url-arguments) thx xyres!

i edited my view to this:

```
class TeamDetail(RetrieveAPIView):
    authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication]
    serializer_class = TeamDetailSerializer

    def get(self, request, company_slug, team_slug):
        if self.request.user.is_anonymous:
            raise Http404()
        companyslug = self.kwargs.get('company_slug')
        teamslug = self.kwargs.get('team_slug')
        if self.request.user.company.slug != companyslug:
            raise Http404()
        company = Company.objects.get(slug=companyslug)
        team = Team.objects.get(company=company, slug=teamslug)
        serializer = TeamDetailSerializer(team)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and this works really fine